# Storing dynamically rendered page elements in state, and keeping variables functional?

Tags: javascript, react-native

I might have asked this question in a confusing way, so I apologize. But I have a map function that renders a lot of text elements dynamically and also styles them based on state. However, the calculations used to create the elements in the first place seems really expensive performance-wise. So I would like to render them once, and then store the created elements in state, and yet still have the styling rerender when it needs to.

I tried storing these mapped elements in an array, but the styling variables inside of each component are set to a single value when the component is stored. So rerendering the page doesn't change the styling of these components even if the initial variables used to set their styles in state have changed.

```
 import React, {useState} from 'react';
 import { Text, View, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';

 export default function App() {
  let [redText, setRedText] = useState(['This', 'That'])
  let [blueText, setBlueText] = useState(['The', 'Other'])
  let str = 'This That And The Other'
  let arr = str.split(" ")
  let componentsArr = null

  function firstRender() {
    componentsArr = []
    componentsArr.push(arr.map((el) => {
      return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Text style={redText.includes(el) 
        ? styles.redText 
        : blueText.includes(el) 
        ? styles.blueText 
        : styles.blackText}>
          {el}
        </Text>
      </View>
    )
  }))
  return componentsArr
  }

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      {componentsArr ? componentsArr : firstRender()}
    </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: "#fff",
    alignItems: "center",
    justifyContent: "center",
  },
  blackText: {
    color: "black"
  },
  redText: {
    color: "red"
  },
  blueText: {
    color: "blue"
  }
});
```

Let's say I have some code like this that adds an onPress event to each element that will automatically change it to red. How can I do that without mapping through and creating the View and Text components from scratch?

When it is initially pushed into the array, all of the styling variables are set in stone. Is there some way to preserve the ternary operations?

Answer (score 1):

i'm not sure i understand well what you wanted to do but as i understood, every word in the text must manage it's own toggle color ? So here how i would go.

```
export const App = () => {
    const [texts, setTexts] = useState(['This', 'That', 'And', 'The', 'Other']);

    const renderTexts = () => {
        return texts.map(text => (
            <CustomTextColorToggle el={text} key={text} />
        ));
    };

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      {renderTexts()}
    </View>
  );
}

// Here defaultColor is optional if you want to add some
// more logic
const CustomTextColorToggle = ({ defaultColor, el }) => {
    const [color, setColor] = useState(defaultColor);
    const styles = color === "red"
                ? styles.redText 
        : color === "blue"
                ? styles.blueText 
        : styles.blackText;

    return (
        <View style={styles.container}>
            <Text style={styles}>
                {el}
            </Text>
        </View>
    );
};
```

Inside CustomTextColorToggle you can wrap the `View` with a `Pressable` to change the color using `setColor`

Comment: This won't rerun the map function every time the color is changed?

Comment: No, only the specific text, add console.log inside CustomTextColorToggle to see the effect

Comment: Nice. Is there any way this can be adapted to change all instances of a particular word at once? Like clicking on "This" changes all instances of the word "This" on the page to red.

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like a good use case for [memoization](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#reactmemo). If you want to prevent rendering of the list and its elements, unless styles change, you need to apply this in two places, the `<View/>` wrapper containing `el` and the entire list itself. Below is how I would apply it.

```
import React, { useState, memo, useEffect } from "react";
import { Text, View, StyleSheet } from "react-native";
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: "#fff",
    alignItems: "center",
    justifyContent: "center",
  },
  blackText: {
    color: "black",
  },
  redText: {
    color: "red",
  },
  blueText: {
    color: "blue",
  },
});

const stylesAreEqual = (prevProps, nextProps) => {
  //we only compare styles since we assume el prop wont change
  return (
    prevProps.redText === nextProps.redText &&
    prevProps.blueText === nextProps.blueText
  );
};
//this component only re-renders if redText or blueText change.
//if el changes, it doesnt re-render. If you want this behavior to change,
//remove the stylesAreEqual function from the memo callback
const ViewItem = ({ el, redText, blueText }) => {
  //responds to any styles passed into the component
  const propStyle = redText.includes(el)
    ? styles.redText
    : blueText.includes(el)
    ? styles.blueText
    : styles.blackText;
  //if you want to control the styles indiviually for each view item without needing
  // to change redText, or blue Text props. It can managed locally here
  const [style, setStyle] = useState(propStyle);
  const onPressEvent = () => {
    //write any change to style on a press
    setStyle({ color: "black" });
  };
  useEffect(() => {
    //if you want to respond to changed passed from a higher up component.
    // though consider using useContext for this if your handling anything other
    // than primary types (i.e strings, boolean, etc.)
    setStyle(propStyle);
  }, [propStyle]);
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Text onPress={onPressEvent} style={style}>
        {el}
      </Text>
    </View>
  );
};
const MemoViewItem = ({ el, redText, blueText }) =>
  memo(
    <ViewItem el={el} redText={redText} blueText={blueText} />,
    stylesAreEqual
  );
const MemoList = ({ arr, redText, blueText }) =>
  //this means that unless the props passed into this component change,
  // it will not re-render, even if a component above it does for any case.
  memo(
    <>
      {arr.map((el) => {
        return <MemoViewItem el={el} redText={redText} blueText={blueText} />;
      })}
    </>
  );
export default function App() {
  let [redText, setRedText] = useState(["This", "That"]);
  let [blueText, setBlueText] = useState(["The", "Other"]);
  let str = "This That And The Other";
  let arr = str.split(" ");
  let componentsArr = null;

  function firstRender() {
    componentsArr = [];
    componentsArr.push(
      <MemoList arr={arr} blueText={blueText} redText={redText} />
    );
    return componentsArr;
  }

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      {componentsArr ? componentsArr : firstRender()}
    </View>
  );
}
```

Since I'm unsure if you want to change styles from onpress events, or from a general state coming from a higher component, I've included both in this example. In addition, depending on your use case, you can modify this above, and test where you need [memoization](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#reactmemo) or not since adding it does add [extra overhead](https://dmitripavlutin.com/use-react-memo-wisely/) if its not necessary.

As a note though, the only way to prevent the list from re-rendering at all (only once on mount), is to manage the styles in **a local component**

In this case, removing `redText` and `blueText` from the App component, and removing the props on every component down the tree. From there, you can manage the styles inside the `ViewItem` component. Should this be the case, you can also remove the `memo` function. Below is an example.

```
import React, { useState, memo } from "react";
import { Text, View, StyleSheet } from "react-native";
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: "#fff",
    alignItems: "center",
    justifyContent: "center",
  },
  blackText: {
    color: "black",
  },
  redText: {
    color: "red",
  },
  blueText: {
    color: "blue",
  },
});


const ViewItem = ({ el }) => {
  //if you want to control the styles indiviually for each view item without needing
  // to change redText, or blue Text props. It can managed locally here
  const [redText, setRedText] = useState(["This", "That"]);
  const [blueText, setBlueText] = useState(["The", "Other"]);
  const style = redText.includes(el)
  ? styles.redText
  : blueText.includes(el)
  ? styles.blueText
  : styles.blackText;
  //const [styles, setStyles] = useState({});
  const onPressEvent = () => {
    //write any change to style on a press
    setRedText("Cool");
  };

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Text onPress={onPressEvent} style={style}>
        {el}
      </Text>
    </View>
  );
};

//prevent list from re-rendering unless app prop changes
const MemoList = ({ arr }) => memo(
  <>
    {arr.map((el) => (
      <ViewItem el={el} />
    ))}
  </>
);

export default function App() {
  let str = "This That And The Other";
  let arr = str.split(" ");
  let componentsArr = null;
  function firstRender() {
    componentsArr = [];
    componentsArr.push(<MemoList arr={arr} />);
    return componentsArr;
  }

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      {componentsArr ? componentsArr : firstRender()}
    </View>
  );
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I am getting a lot of unknown errors when I try this code, though...

Comment: Hey! what are the errors, there could be typos haha. I wrote this pretty quickly

Comment: I imagine it is something I am doing wrong I am new to React Native. The main error says Objects are not valid as a React child. The other one says "memo: The first argument must be a component"

Comment: Fixed the typos! and hmm that's strange. 

Check if any of your functions is returning something other than a JSX.Element or a ReactExoticCompoment (its a component type). If you use vscode, hovering over the function does the trick.

Comment: I don't see anything. I just copy and pasted the entire thing to test it out from scratch.